# How to center a card inside a container ( bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, frontend, bootstrap-5

I have a container and, inside it, a card. I tried using justify-content-center,mx-auto and hardcoding css properties to bring the card to the center of the container, but I did not get the actual output.

Here is my html file

```
<div class="container bg-warning">
    <div class="row  mx-auto centermycard">
        <div class="card mx-auto ">
            <div class="card-title"><h2 class="text-center">Find Lyrics For Your Song</h2></div>
            <div class="card-body ">
                <div class="container">
                    @using (Html.BeginForm("FetchLyrics", "LandingPage", FormMethod.Get, Model))
                    {
                        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Please fix the below errors")

                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.songname, "I want a Song")
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.songname, new { @class = "form-control" })
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.songname)
                        </div>


                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.moviename, "From Movie")
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.moviename, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.artist, "By Artist")
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.artist, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        </div>


                        <div class="form-group">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.genre, "In genre")
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.genre, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group">
                            <button class="btn btn-block btn-primary col-md-8 col-lg-8 text-center justify-content-center">Search</button>
                        </div>
                    }
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

centermycard css properties

```
.centermycard {
   margin:0 auto;
}
```

where did I miss?

Comment: use align-items: center; or align-items-center to center vertically. and justify-content-center or justify-content: center; to center horizontally

Comment: the card should be place inside a column inside the row and not directly in the row

Comment: the card should be place inside a column inside the row and not directly in the row – 
This worked... Hey, thanks for that

Answer (score 0):

Adding the class `mx-auto` to just the card worked fine. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/deathstalkersid/peqxsbwf/3/)

However, I don't understand why you're using a container within a card itself. You already have the entire thing enclosed in a container.

Comment: I dont know much about bootstrap. I am learning by implementing it... thanks for your advice